# How can i merge two columns of a table in sql as a sentence?

Tags: sql, database, string, select, selection

i am a beginner in database programming. I am doing my homework, and i get a task about sql queries. My task is to merge 3 columns(first name, last name, sex) of a table(person) in a sentence.

for example:

```
"John Anderson is a male."

"Julia Smith is a female."
```

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, ||' is a '|| sex ||'.'||    
FROM person    
LIMIT 10
```

and I get this error:

```
ERROR: Operator does not exist: text ||

LINE 1:select first_name, last_name, ||' is a '|| sex ||'.'||
                                                           ^ 
HINT: No operator matches the specified name and argument type. You may have to add explicit type conversions.
```

If anyone can offer me an idea or solution, it would be great for me.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle???

Comment: I think is something like `select first_name + ' ' + last_name + ' is a ' + sex from person limit 10`, at least in sql server.

Comment: i am using PostgreSQL in pgAdmin Platform

Comment: Maybe the error is because you don't need the last || in your sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the way you have written your `SELECT` expression, it should be

```
SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name || ' is a ' || sex || '.'    
FROM person    
LIMIT 10
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=1358cc09fda9a48b1c94880b728d1cc1)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. my problem has been solved.